# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.validators.scatter._line'

Tags: python, plotly

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOl5T.png) I'm trying to make a line graph using the Plotly function, and I've installed the new chart_studio package. I was able to make a graph using this code:

```
a = np.linspace(start=0, stop=36, num=36)

np.random.seed(25)

b = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=36)

trace = go.Scatter(x=a, y=b)

data = [trace]

py.iplot(data, filename='basic-line-chart')
```

Which works and produces a line graph. When I try to import a csv file using Pandas and a line graph using this code I get an error.

```
address = "C:\\Users\\Mattbot\\Documents\\Python Data Science\\Ex_Files_Python_Data_Science_EssT_Pt_1\\Exercise Files\\Data\\mtcars.csv"

cars = pd.read_csv(address)
cars.columns = ['car_names','mpg','cyl','disp', 'hp', 'drat', 'wt', 'qsec', 'vs', 'am', 'gear', 'carb']

df = cars[['cyl', 'wt','mpg']]

layout = dict(title='Chart from Pandas DataFrame', xaxis= dict(title='x-axis'), yaxis= dict(title='y-axis'))

df.iplot(filename='cf-simple-line-chart', layout=layout)
```

I've quoted the whole error below if that's helpful. Sorry in advance for my inexperience with Plotly and python. I tried asking this on the plotly forums but to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-62304e9e67f2> in <module>
      8 layout = dict(title='Chart from Pandas DataFrame', xaxis= dict(title='x-axis'), yaxis= dict(title='y-axis'))
      9 
---> 10 df.iplot(filename='cf-simple-line-chart', layout=layout)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py in _iplot(self, kind, data, layout, filename, sharing, title, xTitle, yTitle, zTitle, theme, colors, colorscale, fill, width, dash, mode, interpolation, symbol, size, barmode, sortbars, bargap, bargroupgap, bins, histnorm, histfunc, orientation, boxpoints, annotations, keys, bestfit, bestfit_colors, mean, mean_colors, categories, x, y, z, text, gridcolor, zerolinecolor, margin, labels, values, secondary_y, secondary_y_title, subplots, shape, error_x, error_y, error_type, locations, lon, lat, asFrame, asDates, asFigure, asImage, dimensions, asPlot, asUrl, online, **kwargs)
    839                 data=df.to_iplot(colors=colors,colorscale=colorscale,kind=kind,interpolation=interpolation,fill=fill,width=width,dash=dash,sortbars=sortbars,keys=keys,
    840                                                 bestfit=bestfit,bestfit_colors=bestfit_colors,mean=mean,mean_colors=mean_colors,asDates=asDates,mode=mode,symbol=symbol,size=size,
--> 841                         text=text,**kwargs)     
    842                                 trace_kw=check_kwargs(kwargs,TRACE_KWARGS)
    843                                 for trace in data:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py in _to_iplot(self, colors, colorscale, kind, mode, interpolation, symbol, size, fill, width, dash, sortbars, keys, bestfit, bestfit_colors, opacity, mean, mean_colors, asDates, asTimestamp, text, **kwargs)
    159                 lines_plotly=[Bar(lines[key]).to_plotly_json() for key in keys]
    160         else:
--> 161                 lines_plotly=[Scatter(lines[key]).to_plotly_json() for key in keys]
    162         for trace in lines_plotly:
    163                 if isinstance(trace['name'],pd.Timestamp):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    159                 lines_plotly=[Bar(lines[key]).to_plotly_json() for key in keys]
    160         else:
--> 161                 lines_plotly=[Scatter(lines[key]).to_plotly_json() for key in keys]
    162         for trace in lines_plotly:
    163                 if isinstance(trace['name'],pd.Timestamp):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_scatter.py in __init__(self, arg, cliponaxis, connectgaps, customdata, customdatasrc, dx, dy, error_x, error_y, fill, fillcolor, groupnorm, hoverinfo, hoverinfosrc, hoverlabel, hoveron, hovertemplate, hovertemplatesrc, hovertext, hovertextsrc, ids, idssrc, legendgroup, line, marker, meta, metasrc, mode, name, opacity, orientation, r, rsrc, selected, selectedpoints, showlegend, stackgaps, stackgroup, stream, t, text, textfont, textposition, textpositionsrc, textsrc, texttemplate, texttemplatesrc, tsrc, uid, uirevision, unselected, visible, x, x0, xaxis, xcalendar, xsrc, y, y0, yaxis, ycalendar, ysrc, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _get_validator(self, prop)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\validator_cache.py in get_validator(parent_path, prop_name)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\importers.py in __getattr__(import_name)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.validators.scatter._line'
```

Comment: I think you are using some sort f old version of documentation. Do you mind to tell us which columns are you trying to plot form `df`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to plot the cyl wt and mpg columns. You mean the code used to create the graph is old?

Comment: I'll be more specific. Are you looking for line plot, scatter plot or other, which one is supposed to be your x and your y?

Comment: line plot, but honestly I'm not sure the original author's y-axis and x-axis is... Sorry I'm using this code from a Linkedin learning set. Doesn't make a lot of sense and the video just shows y-axis and x-axis with 3 different lines

Comment: Hi Matt, do you mind to check if my answer makes sense to you?

Comment: In my case, the problem was Microsoft One drive! because my virtual environment had many files, One drive had some problem synching whole files, and actually for some reason, One drive would not let my python environment access some of the `plotly`'s files! Deactivating (uninstalling) One drive solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the plot you add it seems to me you are looking for something like

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b/raw/5f23f993cd87c283ce766e7ac6b329ee7cc2e1d1/mtcars.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

# these are the columns you want to plot
cols = ['cyl', 'wt','mpg']
# all columns must have the same dtype
# if you want to use plotly.express
df[cols] = df[cols].astype("float")

px.line(df, x=df["model"], y=cols)
```

[image]